# How to code equivalent php function for a given function in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, function, dynamic

I have this PHP code to create a button with an attached JavaScript click event handler to display an alert when it has been pressed.

```
    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['take-attendance'])){
    $date = date("d/m");
    echo'<center><table><tr><th> Student-Id </th> <th> Name </th> <th>'.$date.'</th></tr>';

    foreach($sheet_data as $row) {

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td> <input type = "button"  value = "A" name = "'.$row['id'].'" id = "'.$row['id'].'" class = "apbutton" ></td></tr>';

    }       
     echo '</table></center>';


     echo'<input type="button" name="mark-attendance" id="mark-attendance" value="Mark Attendance" class = "mark-attendance">';

    } 
    ?>
    <script>
    $(".apbutton").on("click", function() {
        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");

        alert(buttonId);
    }); 

    </script>
```

Now I'm trying to write same function but in PHP because I'm facing some problems in executing function further.

Comment: What do you have to do in PHP? Catch a button click and display a message box? It can't be done in pure PHP without JavaScript because PHP is server side but button click occurs client side.

Comment: i want to catch button click in php because it's not just about getting button id but i want to store id of every button clicked in an array and then store it in the mysql databse.

Comment: all in the same function

Comment: @Adriano thanks , i'll try some other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes no sense. Why do you want to translate a javascript function to a php function?

Javascript is meant as a client-side scripting language. When you load a website up with javascript on the page, that javascript code is ran via your client machine or your internet browser, however you want to look at it.

When you load a php script for a website the php code is executed before the page is rendered on the client. The purpose of php is to run on the backend server away from the user. There is no way to literally translate it. The best you could do is have php output javascript code in the returning output.

Comment: You often perform similar tasks especially when you dont want to have to wait for the form to be submitted before knowing its wrong

Comment: Yea but PHP doesn't work like that, it's not made to work like that either. I think I have an idea what you want but this isn't the way to go about it. Look at Ajax here: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))

Comment: "The best you could do is have php output javascript code in the returning output"   can u please help me further n ya is there really no way to handle a button click event for a dynamically generated button in php ?? i'm not getting it

Comment: You need to use ajax/javascript to do that. What you want to do is not possible with PHP. What I explained was a bit of a hack that I don't recommend using anyway.

Comment: Got it !! will use Ajax/javascript, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by turning the button into an `anchor` tag, and adding the button ID to the href url.  However this would reload the page, but you would have a PHP solution.  Obviously there is no PHP function for `alert`.

Comment: thanks but i dont wanna use anchor

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the snippet of code you've given is all you have. I assume not. For example, what is $sheet_data? We have no way of knowing.
Starting from what you gave us I have made some changes to your code:

- I have hard coded some values for the $sheet_data array
- I have added some tags: html, head and body
- I added a reference to jquery
- I removed the if statement as your snippet doesn't contain any info on how this post variable gets filled (no form, no submit,...)

The result of that is below and does work as you intended. So if it doesn't for you one of those four changes might contain the clue to what you're doing wrong.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
<?php

    $sheet_data[] = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Bart');
    $sheet_data[] = array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Mark');
    $sheet_data[] = array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Paul');

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Brussels');
    $date = date("d/m");
    echo'<center><table><tr><th> Student-Id </th> <th> Name </th> <th>'.$date.'</th></tr>';

    foreach($sheet_data as $row) {

        echo '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td> <input type = "button"  value = "A" name = "'.$row['id'].'" id = "'.$row['id'].'" class = "apbutton" ></td></tr>';

    }       
     echo '</table></center>';


     echo'<input type="button" name="mark-attendance" id="mark-attendance" value="Mark Attendance" class = "mark-attendance">';


    ?>
    <script>
    $(".apbutton").on("click", function() {
        var buttonId = $(this).attr("id");

        alert(buttonId);
    }); 

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Personally I would put your script block between the head tags and I would add `$( document ).ready()`. See http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ for more information.

While it is correct that you will need ajax to get the data into your database, you will still need to catch the click event as a trigger to start the ajax functionallity. It's the `alert(buttonId);` line that will be replaced by the ajax call.

Comment: yaa i really need to learn ajax , thanks !!